# divs floating over each other vertically

Tags: html, css

I have the following:

```
<!-- BLUE BOX --!>
<div style="width:100%;position:relative;min-height:100%">
   <div style="position:absolute;left:1px;top:15px;">
            IMAGE GOES HERE
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;left:20px;top:0;background-color:#2b5797; color:#fff;width:80%;min-height:40px;border-radius:5px;padding:10px;">
            messages go here
    </div>
</div>
<!-- PINK BOX --!>
<div style="width:100%;position:relative;min-height:100%">
     <div style="position:absolute;right:1px;top:15px;">
       IMAGE HERE
      </div>
      <div style="position:absolute;right:20px;top:0;background-color:#b91d47; color:#fff;width:80%;border-radius:5px;padding:10px;min-height:40px">
            messages go here
      </div>
</div>
```

here is the image of the HTML output:
[image: 1]

Please help me getting those divs in vertical order, I don't want them to float over each other, I want the message div to get the automatic height according to content too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use floats for this. float:left , float:right and a clear:both inbetween :

```
<div style="width:100%;position:relative;min-height:100%;float:left">
    <div style="float:left">img</div>
    <div style="float:left;background-color:#2b5797; color:#fff;width:80%;min-height:40px;border-radius:5px;padding:10px;">First messages go here</div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;width:100%;position:relative;min-height:100%">
    <div style="float:right">img</div>
    <div style="float:right;background-color:#b91d47; color:#fff;width:80%;border-radius:5px;padding:10px;min-height:40px">messages go here</div>
</div>
```

You can see it in action here : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/basarat/y44NC/1/) [image: Screenshot from jsFiddle]

Answer (score 2):

Remove **absolute** position form your message DIV. Write like this:

```
<div style="position:relative;">
   <div style="position:absolute;left:1px;top:15px;">
            IMAGE GOES HERE
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left:20px;margin-right:20%;background-color:#2b5797; color:#fff;min-height:40px;border-radius:5px;padding:10px;">
            messages go here
    </div>
</div>

<div style="position:relative;">
     <div style="position:absolute;right:1px;top:15px;">
       IMAGE HERE
      </div>
      <div style="margin-right:20px;margin-left:20%;background-color:#b91d47; color:#fff;border-radius:5px;padding:10px;min-height:40px">
            messages go here
      </div>
</div>
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/y44NC/2/